Metrics of a classification problem after k-fold cross-validation
I have a classification problem in which the dataset is made up of several smaller datasets $D_1, \cdots, D_k$.
I want to learn a classifier $h_i$ for each $i=1,\cdots, k$, using $D_1, \cdots, D_{i-1}, D_{i+1}, \cdots, D_k$ for training and $D_i$ for testing (i.e. each smaller dataset is a "fold").
The particularity of this problem is that not all $D_i$ are equal in size, and not all the classes considered in the classification problem are present in each $D_i$. The dataset is very umbalanced too.
After training, in each fold I obtain a confusion matrix $C_i$ for each classifier. There are two possible approaches to compute metrics (accuracy and recall, precision, F1-score are the ones I am interested in):

Sum the confusion matrices, this is equivalent to computing the CM on the concatenated predictions from all classifiers. Compute the metrics from the summed CM.
Compute the metrics for each classifier, using the corresponding CM, then average the metrics across classifiers.

I think the first option is the most sensible, since not all $D_i$ have the same size, and there is some $D_i$ with missing classes. The summed confusion matrix has values on all rows, therefore metrics can be computed.
In the second case, there is yet another path that can be taken, by computing the metrics per-class and then averaging (macro-metric) (which is weird, since some classes are missing for some classifiers) then computing the average metric across classifiers or taking the average across classifiers of the per-class metric first, and then averaging (macro-metric).
It says here to sum:

How is the confusion matrix reported from K-fold cross-validation?
Generation of a concatenated Confusion Matrix in cross-validation
How can I create a single confusion matrix after K fold cross validation ?
Chatgpt, prompt: In a cross-validation, I obtain the confusion matrix of k models with c classes each. How do I compute the f1 score?
In phind I get the same answer.
Many papers I've read about my problem use this method.

It says here to first compute, then average:

Cross-Validation in Machine Learning: How to Do It Right 
No papers I've read about my problem state they do it this way.

My supervisor said that summing confusion matrices is not the proper way, so I'm confused.
What is the best way to compute metrics in this case?

Do not use confusion matrices in the first place. They suffer from all the same issues as accuracy, precision, recall etc., especially for "unbalanced" data, but also in general.
Instead, use probabilistic classifiers and assess these using proper scoring rules.
And now your problem vanishes: proper scoring rules assign a value to each instance, based on its probabilistic class membership prediction and its actual class membership. So you just need to store these values for all the instances in your fold $D_i$. If different $D_i$s have different sizes, that just means that some will have more scores than others. No matter: at the end, simply average over all instances, regardless of which fold they are in.

Hi, thanks for the reply, I'll have a look. The problem is that the metrics often used in my problem by other people are the ones I listed in the question: accuracy, recall, precision and F1-score, so at least I should also compute those numbers.
